# How to get time zone using xamarin in android & iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, timezone

I want to get the time zone of the mobile phone's time.

How can I make it?

I am using Xamarin to implement APP in both android / iOS

What I want is to get such as "GMT+8". Not country name.

Comment: `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now)`

Comment: @SushiHangover I have tried this. But I got 0 as reponse. Does this need any permission?

Comment: @CC.Wang - "GMT+8" is not a time zone.  It is an offset from GMT.  Those are very different things.  Please read [the time zone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), especially the section titled *"Time Zone != Offset"*.   If you are actually looking for an *offset*, there are several ways to get it - but all will require some point in time as the basis.  You can use "now" as the basis, but depending on the time zone, that value might be different at some other date and time.   In other words, it's a 1-to-N relationship; a *time zone* has one or more *offsets*.

Comment: @SushiHangover -  Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezone#remarks): *"Whenever possible, use the TimeZoneInfo class instead of the TimeZone class."*   You could do `TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now)`, or `DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset`, or a variety of other approaches, but you should not use the `TimeZone` class, or you might get inaccurate results in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
TimeSpan ts = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).Offset;
```